# Bug in 200 points/day limit logic?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I understand about the 200 cap on reputation gained per day by upvotes of answers.  It was my understanding that the reputation gained from answers being accepted were exempt from this limit, and I'm pretty sure I've seen this in action before.

However, what happened yesterday confuses me and is inconsistant with the logic as I understand it.  Here is a screen shot of the relevant reputation summary:

[image]

Shouldn't the reputation have been 215 instead of 205?  Am I confused or is this a bug?

Comment: Don't you have enough rep?

Comment: @mjh2007: I'm not worried about the 10 rep, but this either means I have a misunderstanding how the system works, or there is a bug in the system.

Comment: Yeah I know I was only kidding with you since you have 22k rep already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what happened was that on October 25th (normally I won't expose this but since it's positive and it helps explain quite a bit, I will) the question owner upvoted your answer.

A day later when they accepted it they removed their upvote (by accident I imagine since...) then immediately re-upvoted it.  This means the +10 that was part of the rep cap on October 25th moved to October 26th.  The way the system works (currently) is it doesn't do an exhaustive back-search and recalc on the way when a vote deletion (the un-upvote) happens to see if you *still* should have hit the rep cap with other votes.

To fix this up you need to trigger a rep recalc which you can do yourself at the bottom here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/reputation (note though, this usually results in a rep lost due to migrated/deleted questions that the votes are now gone for - but it will update your rep to the correct totals. and fix the rep cap history)

Comment: Thanks, Nick.  So it's a minor quirk in how the system works.  Thanks for explaining.  This is such a unusual corner case it's fine to just say that's how it works.

Comment: @Olin - yup...but things like this bug us too, we're finally working on a long-term solution now, should roll out in the coming weeks :)